# Need to remove text from string up to a certain point

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have a script that creates tasks from emails in Outlook - currently it just takes the email subject and makes it the task title, which is fine except I want to get rid of the first portion of the subject line up to a certain point.

The email subjects always start the same (although the ticket number is different), an example subject would be:

```
New Ticket: 3416 - School: School1 - Room: 158 - Desc: Broken PC
```

The ticket number changes - but I would like to remove everything up to and including "School:"

So we would be left with something like this:

```
School1 - Room: 158 - Desc: Broken PC
```

The script I am currently using is this:

```
    Sub MakeTaskFromMail2(MyMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim strID As String
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
    Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    With objTask
        .subject = olMail.subject
        .DueDate = olMail.SentOn
        .Body = olMail.Body
    End With
    Call CopyAttachments(olMail, objTask)
    objTask.Save

    Set objTask = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub

Sub CopyAttachments(objSourceItem, objTargetItem)
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set fldTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
   strPath = fldTemp.Path & "\"
   For Each objAtt In objSourceItem.Attachments
      strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName
      objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
      objTargetItem.Attachments.Add strFile, , , objAtt.DisplayName
      fso.DeleteFile strFile
   Next

   Set fldTemp = Nothing
   Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help on how to separate this out and remove the first portion would be very helpful.

I don't believe it will be too hard to do - but my knowledge of VB is pretty limited.

*Edit - removed vb.net as it is not appropriate here.

Comment: You mentioned VB.NET in tags, but this really isn't an option correct?

Comment: I'm not exactly super familiar with the VB side of things - I am assuming based on your comment I should remove that tag?  Are the macros not VB.net?

Comment: I think so, AFAIK VBA doesn't support .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of Instr/Mid functions

```
Dim sInput As String
Dim sOutput As String

sInput = "New Ticket: 3416 - School: School1 - Room: 158 - Desc: Broken PC"
sOutput = Mid(sInput, InStr(sInput, "School:") + 8)
```

Comment: I am getting 'unexpected end of statement' at the "=" in each of those lines.

Comment: Ups, sorry forgot - no inline initializations, edited

Comment: That got rid of it - thanks!  Testing now to ensure it works appropriately.  I appreciate your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, you can accomplish this easily with RegEx, like this:

```
Dim output As String = RegEx.Replace(input, "New Ticket: \d+ - School: ", "")
```

The `\d` means any digit and the `+` means one or more times.  So, `\d+` together means that it will match any number with one or more digits.

In VB Script or VBA, however, you'll need to resort to the string parsing functions like `Mid` and `InStr`.

Comment: I get 'unexpected end of statement'

Comment: If you are using VB Script or VBA, this will not work.  Use Yuriy's solution instead, it's a very good solution for those languages.